# UIScrollview inclined

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I'm trying use a UIScrollview inclined 350 degrees, the first thing I thought was use the transform attr, the inclination on the scroll worked, but everything on the scroll looks wrong now, when I talk everything I means the position and size of all children of this scroll. I tried some different approach but it didn't work.
Some one have an idea if is it possible?

Thanks,
J.S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the transformation in a UIView that includes your UIScrollView, and not in the UISCrollView directly.

Be sure that all the views do not have autoresizingMask. This way the UIScrollView will have a better look than when you apply directly the transform on it.

The transformation that I used was the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation.